# Ajax does not function in the second row of my table

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, ajax

I have a table which populate list of items, when I select an item from the list, its fetches a price from the database into an input field. The problem here is that, only the first row of the table works, when I select from the second row, it does not work at all. Thanks

**the table**

```
<div class="widget-content no-padding">
  <table class="table table-hover table-striped table-bordered table-highlight-head" id="sample_tbl">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th>Item name</th>
        <th>Quantity</th>
        <th>Price</th>
        <th>Amount</th>
        <th>Description</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td class="col-md-3">
          <select name="item_name" class=" select2 form-control" required="required" id="item_name">
            <option></option>
            <?php $u_qry=$ link->query("select * from items"); while($list = mysqli_fetch_array($u_qry)) { echo"
            <option value=\ "{$list['items_code']}\">{$list['item_name']}</option>"; } ?>
          </select>
        </td>
        <td>
          <input type="text" class="form-control">
        </td>
        <td>
          <input type="text" class="form-control" id="price">
        </td>
        <td>
          <input type="text" class="form-control">
        </td>
        <td>
          <input type="text" class="form-control">
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td class="col-md-3">
          <select name="item_name" class=" select2 form-control" required="required" id="item_name">
            <option></option>
            <?php $u_qry=$ link->query("select * from items"); while($list = mysqli_fetch_array($u_qry)) { echo"
            <option value=\ "{$list['items_code']}\">{$list['item_name']}</option>"; } ?>
          </select>
        </td>
        <td>
          <input type="text" class="form-control">
        </td>
        <td>
          <input type="text" class="form-control" id="price">
        </td>
        <td>
          <input type="text" class="form-control">
        </td>
        <td>
          <input type="text" class="form-control">
        </td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>
```

**ajax**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  $(document).ready(function() {
    $("#item_name").change(function() {
      var item = $("#item_name").val();
      $.ajax({
        type: "post",
        url: "auto_item_price.php",
        data: "item_name=" + item,
        success: function(data) {
          console.log(data);
          $("#price").val(data);
        }
      });
    });
  });
</script>
```

**php**

```
<?php
    include("includes/db_connect.php");
    $item_id = $_POST['item_name'];
    $sql = $link->query("SELECT * FROM items WHERE items_code = $item_id");
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($sql)) {
        echo "{$row['purchase_price']}";
    }
?>
```

Comment: This is because you have duplicate `id` attributes - they ***must*** be unique within the page otherwise only the first element of the set is retrieved. Use a class instead.

Comment: Please format your code, for the sake of readers and your own sanity. :)

Comment: Please which ID are you referring to?

Comment: when i change the price ID to class, it fills the second row with the price of the first row